# Using a different value from a drop down list

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

Sorry my title is crap but cant think of a better way to put it.

Using MS VS 2013 and MS SQL server 2012.  VB

I have a drop down list and the stored procedure it calls gets two values from a table in SQL.  The values are the ID and the name.  The drop down list is displaying the name but I want to use the ID when a name is selected in the drop down list in code.

How do I do this?

My code for the DDL is

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDLAllTreatments" runat="server" DataSourceID="AllTreatments" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Name"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="AllTreatments" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:InfinitySPa %>" SelectCommand="SP_GetAllTreatments" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change DataValueField to ID:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDLAllTreatments" runat="server" DataSourceID="AllTreatments" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="ID"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="AllTreatments" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:InfinitySPa %>" SelectCommand="SP_GetAllTreatments" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: OK thanks but how do I then use it because if I do treatname = ddl.datavalue it doesn't work